# Upload zip file using --archives option of spark-submit on yarn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, zip, hadoop-yarn

I have a directory with some model files and my application has to access these models files in local file system due to some reason.

Of course I know that `--files` option of `spark-submit` can upload file to the working directory of each executor and it does work.

However, I want keep the directory structure of my files so I come up with `--archives` option, which is said

```
YARN-only:
......
--archives ARCHIVES         Comma separated list of archives to be extracted into the working directory of each executor.
......
```

But when I actually use it to upload `models.zip`, I found yarn just put it there without extraction, like what it did with `--files`. Have I misunderstood `to be extracted` or misused this option?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

YARN does extract the archive but add an extra folder with the same name of the archive. To make it clear, If I put `models/model1` and `models/models2` in `models.zip`, then I have to access my models by `models.zip/models/model1` and `models.zip/models/model2`.

Moreover, we can make this more beautiful using the # syntax.

***The --files and --archives options support specifying file names with the # similar to Hadoop. For example you can specify: --files localtest.txt#appSees.txt and this will upload the file you have locally named localtest.txt into HDFS but this will be linked to by the name appSees.txt, and your application should use the name as appSees.txt to reference it when running on YARN.***

Edit:

This answer was tested on spark 2.0.0 and I'm not sure the behavior in other versions.

Comment: This has just been a life saver. Was it documented anywhere?!

Comment: Glad it helped. I found no document about this and I think this should appear in `spark-submit -h`.

Comment: This saved me too.  Best answer on stackoverflow. By the way, from what I could tell it didn't extract the file UNLESS I added # and an alias.  Maybe it was the version of spark or something strange.  But I recommend just adding the # alias for anyone struggling with this.

Comment: Is there any way of extracting zip without adding #  ?

Comment: @RakeshSKadam The # is just to create an alias to make it easier for you to reference the files in your jobs/scripts.  Without a "#" it will just extract the zip into a folder of the same name as the zip file - like the OP indicates.

Comment: Hi @MoTao - I have similar problem. I have spark-submit command like 'spark-submit --master yarn-client  --driver-memory 4g --py-files /home/valli/pyFiles.zip --archives /home/valli/sql.zip#sqls /home/valli/main.py --sqls-path /home/valli/sqls'. But still I'm getting 'FileNotFound' exception when I trying to access sql files in zip folder. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MoTao does this #appSees.txt option work with s3 as source ? I am trying to spark-submit as ```"spark-submit","--master","yarn","--jars","s3://xxx.jar","--py-files","s3://xxx.py","--archives","s3://xxxutils.zip#utils","s3://xxx.py","--deploy-mode","cluster"```