# spark on yarn and --archives option

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to utilize the --archives option available in spark-on-yarn in order to upload an archive file. Based on the documentation & as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498365/upload-zip-file-using-archives-option-of-spark-submit-on-yarn), yarn will not only upload the zip file but will also automatically unarchive the zip file on the worker nodes.

From the logs, I can see that yarn is uploading the jar in spark's staging directory e.g.

```
17/09/19 01:28:57 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/foo/bar/zoo.zip -> hdfs://abc.foo.bar:8020/user/xyz/.sparkStaging/application_1503584958553_4501/zoo.zip
```

The issue I am facing is that, although the zip file is getting copied into spark staging directory, it's not getting automatically unarchived & I am guessing it's also not getting copied in the worker nodes.

Assuming yarn does unarchive the zip files, is there a way to access the location of worker nodes programmatically?

I am running spark 2.2 against emr 5.8 which is having yarn 2.7.

Comment: Hi @Pawan - Have you find any solution for this. I'm facing the same problem. Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498365/upload-zip-file-using-archives-option-of-spark-submit-on-yarn

Answer (score 3):

To unarchive the zip into your desired directory you need to give following values

`--archives src.zip#src`

This means that the src.zip will be uploaded to all executors and unarchived into "src" directory. Another example to make it clearer -

`--archives src.zip#abc`

If you change the directory name (string after #) like above, now src.zip will be unarchived into "abc" directory.

Comment: will it be copied into the new nodes if there will be an autoscaling?